# Yii - filtering model findAll by multiple column values?

Tags: yii

```
$models = ClientsDatabases::model->findAllByAttributes(array(
  'active' => 1, 
  'suspended' => 0 
 ));
```

I'd like to also filter this by specific values for multiple columns. Eg:

```
   $filters = array( 
        array( 'master_db' => 2, 'db_id' => 3 ), 
        array( 'master_db' => 2, 'db_id' => 2 ), 
   )
```

What methods can I use to filter by those specific column values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using scopes to accomplish this?

Controller:
`$model = ClientsDatabases::model()->active()->suspended()->findAll();`

Model:

```
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'active' => array(
            'condition' => 'active = 1'
        ),
        'suspended' => array(
            'condition' => 'suspended = 0'
        ),
    );
}
```

If you want to pass values, instead of defining a default scope like that, try using this:

Model:

```
public function active($active = 0) {
    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'condition' => "active = {$active}"
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

Then your controller would look something like this: `$model = ClientDatabases::model()->active(1)->suspended()->findAll();`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you provide an example using `master_db` and `db_id`? Since they need very specific values and it's multiple rather than the simple `active` conditions.

Comment: Could you provide some context as to what `master_db` and `db_id` are? Are they two separate tables that have relations, or are you using them to refer to a specific table?

Comment: I'm using them to refer to external databases - I have a separate class that connects to the master db which houses sites and db connections for those sites, and thats where the sub db is used. I just need something equivalent to `SELECT * FROM clients_databases WHERE active 1 AND ( ( master_db=1 AND db_id=3 ) OR ( master_db = 2 AND db_id = 1 ) )`. Maybe the best way is just a raw query?

Comment: You might look into Yii's `with()` method. In your model class you'll need to define a `relations()` function, but I am uncertain if this will work across multiple database connections. Your `$model` will look something like this `$model = ClientDatabases::model()->with('table1','table2')->active(1)->suspended()->findAll();`